# Ffmpeg streaming from capturing device Osprey 450e fails

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, live-streaming

i want to encode live stream video with ffmpeg capturing from Directshow card(Osprey Card 450e) to mp4 streaming multicast. For the moment i have this error.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Osprey-450e Video Device 1A":audio="Osprey-450e Audio Device 1A" -f mpegts -b:v 5120k -r 30 -c:v mpeg2video -c:a ac3 -b:a 256k udp://239.192.42.61:1234

[dshow @ 02c7f640] Could not run filter video=Osprey-450e Video Device 1A:Audio?Osprey-450e Audio Device 1A: Input/output error
```

Ffmpeg can encode a Directshow input?

Answer (score 0):

Is your device a crossbar device?  ffmpeg does not currently support those devices.

Also see here - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow

> If you have a video capture card (ex: AverMedia, possibly some BlackMagic, though it may be a separate unrelated problem, and also some BlackMagic cards don't have the right inputs set up ask on the forum), it may not work (yet) out of the box with FFmpeg, as it lacks crossbar support presently. The work around currently is to install the AmerecTV software, which presents the capture card as directshow devices, then input the AmerecTV directshow devices into your FFmpeg.

Comment: crossbar support has been recently added now, FWIW