# Saving highest quality video from video-capture card

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I have a machine with 2x3 3ghz dual-core xeon and 4x10krpm scsi 320 disks in raid0.
The capture card is an osprey 560 64 bit pci card.
Operating system is currently Windows Server 2003.

The video-stream that I can open with VLC using direct show is rather nice quality.
However, trying to save this video-stream without loss of quality has proven quite difficult,
using the h264 codec I am able to achieve a satisfying quality, however, all 4 cores jump to 100% load after a few second and then it start dropping frames, the machine is not powerful enough for realtime encoding. I've not been able to achieve satisfying mpeg1 or 4 quality, no matter which bitrate I set..

Thing is, the disks in this machine are pretty fast even by todays standard, and they are bored.. I don't care about disk-usage, I want quality.
I have searched in vain for a way to pump that beautiful videostream that I see in VLC onto the disk for later encoding, I reckon the disks would be fast enough, or maybe something which would apply a light compression, enough that the disks can keep up, but not so much as to loose visible quality.

I have tried FFMPEG as it seems capable of streaming a yuv4 stream down to the disk, but ofcause FFMPEG is unable to open the dshow device ( same error as this guy [Ffmpeg streaming from capturing device Osprey 450e fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288671/ffmpeg-streaming-from-capturing-device-osprey-450e-fails) )

Please recommend a capable and (preferably) software which can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it out, it is deceptively simple:
Just uncheck the "transcode" option in the window where you can select an encoding preset.
2 gigabytes per minutes is a low price to pay for finally getting those precious memories off of old videotapes in the quality they deserve.